# I upgraded my server to 12.10, why does PHP not work with nginx?

Tags: upgrade, php, 12.10, nginx

I upgraded and now I can't use my nginx's `proxy_pass` arguments on my Ubuntu server to work with PHP.  I keep getting `502 Bad Gateway` errors.  Why is this, and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this LaunchPad Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/php5/+bug/900620) and [this Debian bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=650204), it was requested that Debian/Ubuntu have `php5-fpm` listen on a UNIX socket by default.  This was adopted in `5.4.0-rc1`, and remains in place in the Ubuntu Quantal (and likely later) packages (this was a package-only change, not an upstream one).

The solution (as outlined in [my blog post on this matter](http://lordoftime.info/?p=39)) is to change where your `proxy_pass` points to, so that it points to `unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock` which is now the default location for `php5-fpm` to set its listener to (this apples to `php5` package versions `5.4.0-rc1` and later in both Ubuntu and Debian at the time of this post, and only to the versions in the main repositories, and not PPAs).

**This applies to Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal) and later!**